# Recommendations for integrating argparse scripts in Python's unit tests via nose or pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, argparse, nose, pytest

My [recent project](https://github.com/rasbt/pyprot) consists mainly of an API for which I have written some unit tests for `pytest` and `nose`.

I have some scripts in this bundle that make use of this API and was wondering if there is a good way to include them in those unit tests.

There would be the `subprocess.call` way, but I think this is rather ugly. Do you have any recommendations how I can integrate those scripts?

Comment: Have you looked at `test_argparse.py` to see how it tests `argparse`?  It either calls `parser.parse_args('a string of inputs'.split())` or sets `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your scripts in python if it not already. And just import it in your tests.